# Android go to actual sms conversation

Tags: android

I am working on app that checks if a new sms comes via sms receiver and if does, I am showing notification. When notification is clicked, I am opening default sms messaging application like this:

```
  // start default messenging app on notification click
  Intent resultIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
  resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  resultIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");

  TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
  stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

  // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
  stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
  PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

This works fine. However is there anyway to actually go into actual conversation for the number SMS was received from instead of just opening default sms app ? In other words, I want to go inside the conversation of recieved sms not just default main inbox where all recepients are. Thanks for the help

Comment: "I am opening default sms messaging application" -- no, you are opening something that matches your stated `Intent`. There is no requirement for a device's "default sms messaging application" to match this, and there is no requirement that the user's preferred SMS client has to match this.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks for pointing that out :) Well then wonder how would I open whatever default sms app they have set ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer again myself:

```
public static Intent getSmsToIntent(Context context, String phoneNumber) {

    Intent popup = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);

    // Should *NOT* be using FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK however something
    // is broken on
    // a few popular devices that received recent Froyo upgrades that means
    // this is required
    // in order to refresh the system compose message UI
    int flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
    // Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP;
    // Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK;

    popup.setFlags(flags);

    if (!"".equals(phoneNumber)) {
        // Log.v("^^Found threadId (" + threadId +
        // "), sending to Sms intent");
        popup.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + Uri.encode(phoneNumber)));
    } else {
        return getSmsInboxIntent(context);
    }
    return popup;
}
```